# Revit Transform Matrix from point cloud to revit link

Tags: api, revit

We insert a point cloud in Revit and have to move and rotate it in several axles to get a good world alignment.  We then need to apply the same transforms to a Revit MEP link that contains edgwise piping.
I have acquired the 3x4 matrix from the point cloud in revit,  I would like to apply that to the revit mep link so that they are in alignment.

I have successfully applied the translation portion of the transform, I am stuck on the rotation portion.  Could someone please assist with this.  Dyslexia and Matrices do not work well together.

Thanks to Jeremy at the Building Coder for getting me this far!

9/4/19 - I edited the rotational part of the code,  however the "ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement" does not have any effect on the link in Revit.

```
Autodesk.Revit.DB.View
pView = ActiveUIDocument.Document.ActiveView;Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transaction
    t = new Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transaction(ActiveUIDocument.Document, "EdgewiseCoordination");
    t.Start();

        UIDocument uidoc = this.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document document = uidoc.Document;
        Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application application = document.Application;

        ElementId elementid = null;
        elementid = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Select element to Copy Transform or ESC to reset the view").ElementId;

            Element e = document.GetElement(elementid);

            Instance ei = e as Instance;

            Transform pct = ei.GetTransform();

        ElementId elementid2 = null;
            elementid2 = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Select element to Apply Transform or ESC to reset the view").ElementId;

                Element e2 = document.GetElement(elementid2);

                Instance ei2 = e2 as Instance;

                ElementTransformUtils.MoveElement(document,elementid2,pct.Origin);

                Line lineaxis = GetRotationAxisFromTransform(pct);
                double tangle = GetRotationAngleFromTransform(pct);

                ElementTransformUtils.RotateElement(document,elementid2,lineaxis,tangle);

        t.Commit(); 

}


private static Line GetRotationAxisFromTransform(Transform transform)
{
  double x = transform.BasisY.Z - transform.BasisZ.Y;
  double y = transform.BasisZ.X - transform.BasisX.Z;
  double z = transform.BasisX.Y - transform.BasisY.X;

  return Line.CreateUnbound(transform.Origin, new XYZ(x, y, z));
}

private static double GetRotationAngleFromTransform(Transform transform)
{
  double x = transform.BasisX.X;
  double y = transform.BasisY.Y;
  double z = transform.BasisZ.Z;

  double trace = x + y + z;

  return Math.Acos((trace - 1) / 2.0);
}       



Earlier Code to save out the transform----------------------------------

public void Objectlocation()
{

    Autodesk.Revit.DB.View
    pView = ActiveUIDocument.Document.ActiveView;Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transaction
        t = new Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transaction(ActiveUIDocument.Document, "Objectlocation");
        t.Start();

            UIDocument uidoc = this.ActiveUIDocument;
            Document document = uidoc.Document;
            Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application application = document.Application;

            ElementId elementid = null;
            elementid = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Select element or ESC to reset the view").ElementId;

                Element e = document.GetElement(elementid);

                Instance ei = e as Instance;

                Transform pct = ei.GetTransform();

                //string spctrans = TransformString(pct);
                //TaskDialog.Show("Point Cloud Transform", spctrans);

                //spctrans = (spctrans + ",0,0,0,1");

                string slocx = TransformStringX(pct);
                string slocy = TransformStringY(pct);
                string slocz = TransformStringZ(pct);

                string slocation = (slocx + "," + slocy + "," + slocz + ",0,0,0,1");

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
                {
                   sw.WriteLine(slocation);
                }

        t.Commit(); 

}

static public string RealString( double a )
{
return a.ToString( "0.####################" );
}

static public string PointStringX( XYZ p )
{
    double convunit = 0;
    convunit = UnitUtils.ConvertFromInternalUnits(p.X,DisplayUnitType.DUT_DECIMAL_INCHES);

return string.Format( "{0}", RealString( convunit ));
}

static public string TransformStringX( Transform t )
{
return string.Format( "{0},{1},{2},{3}", PointStringX( t.BasisX ),
PointStringX( t.BasisY ), PointStringX( t.BasisZ ), PointStringX( t.Origin ) );
}

static public string PointStringY( XYZ p )
{
    double convunit = 0;
    convunit = UnitUtils.ConvertFromInternalUnits(p.Y,DisplayUnitType.DUT_DECIMAL_INCHES);
return string.Format( "{0}", RealString( convunit ));
}

static public string TransformStringY( Transform t )
{
return string.Format( "{0},{1},{2},{3}", PointStringY( t.BasisX ),
PointStringY( t.BasisY ), PointStringY( t.BasisZ ), PointStringY( t.Origin ) );
}

static public string PointStringZ( XYZ p )
{
    double convunit = 0;
    convunit = UnitUtils.ConvertFromInternalUnits(p.Z,DisplayUnitType.DUT_DECIMAL_INCHES);
return string.Format( "{0}", RealString( convunit ));
}

static public string TransformStringZ( Transform t )
{
return string.Format( "{0},{1},{2},{3}", PointStringZ( t.BasisX ),
PointStringZ( t.BasisY ), PointStringZ( t.BasisZ ), PointStringZ( t.Origin ) );
}


I edited the stuff you had on bcoder to split up the matrix in order to match the acad api that I was feeding it into.

ACAD API below-----------------------------------------------------------


using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

using System.Reflection;



namespace Transformer

{

    public class Commands

    {

        [CommandMethod("TRANS", CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]

        static public void TransformEntity()

        {

            Document doc =

              Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

            Database db = doc.Database;

            Editor ed = doc.Editor;



            // Our selected entity (only one supported, for now)



            ObjectId id;



            // First query the pickfirst selection set



            PromptSelectionResult psr = ed.SelectImplied();

            if (psr.Status != PromptStatus.OK || psr.Value == null)

            {

                // If nothing selected, ask the user



                PromptEntityOptions peo =

                  new PromptEntityOptions(

                    "\nSelect entity to transform: "

                  );

                PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity(peo);

                if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)

                    return;

                id = per.ObjectId;

            }

            else

            {

                // If the pickfirst set has one entry, take it



                SelectionSet ss = psr.Value;

                if (ss.Count != 1)

                {

                    ed.WriteMessage(

                      "\nThis command works on a single entity."

                    );

                    return;

                }

                ObjectId[] ids = ss.GetObjectIds();

                id = ids[0];

            }



            PromptResult pr = ed.GetString("\nEnter property name: ");

            if (pr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)

                return;



            string prop = pr.StringResult;



            // Now let's ask for the matrix string



            pr = ed.GetString("\nEnter matrix values: ");

            if (pr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)

                return;



            // Split the string into its individual cells



            string[] cells = pr.StringResult.Split(new char[] { ',' });

            if (cells.Length != 16)

            {

                ed.WriteMessage("\nMust contain 16 entries.");

                return;

            }



            try

            {

                // Convert the array of strings into one of doubles



                double[] data = new double[cells.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)

                {

                    data[i] = double.Parse(cells[i]);

                }



                // Create a 3D matrix from our cell data



                Matrix3d mat = new Matrix3d(data);



                // Now we can transform the selected entity



                Transaction tr =

                  doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();

                using (tr)

                {

                    Entity ent =

                      tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite)

                      as Entity;

                    if (ent != null)

                    {

                        bool transformed = false;



                        // If the user specified a property to modify



                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop))

                        {

                            // Query the property's value



                            object val =

                              ent.GetType().InvokeMember(

                                prop, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, ent, null

                              );



                            // We only know how to transform points and vectors



                            if (val is Point3d)

                            {

                                // Cast and transform the point result



                                Point3d pt = (Point3d)val,

                                        res = pt.TransformBy(mat);



                                // Set it back on the selected object



                                ent.GetType().InvokeMember(

                                  prop, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,

                                  ent, new object[] { res }

                                );

                                transformed = true;

                            }

                            else if (val is Vector3d)

                            {

                                // Cast and transform the vector result



                                Vector3d vec = (Vector3d)val,

                                        res = vec.TransformBy(mat);



                                // Set it back on the selected object



                                ent.GetType().InvokeMember(

                                  prop, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,

                                  ent, new object[] { res }

                                );

                                transformed = true;

                            }

                        }



                        // If we didn't transform a property,

                        // do the whole object



                        if (!transformed)

                            ent.TransformBy(mat);

                    }

                    tr.Commit();

                }

            }

            catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)

            {

                ed.WriteMessage(

                  "\nCould not transform entity: {0}", ex.Message

                );

            }

        }

    }

}

END ACAD API
```

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation, and congratulations on realising this impressive result so far!

Comment: I agree with your approach using `MoveElement` and `RotateElement`. Are you sure you need rotations around all three axes? Do you know what the transformation does at all? Maybe it only rotates around one axis? Can you describe the total transformation? Provide a minimal sample model? Make a drawing illustrating the situation?

Comment: Thanks,  it's been a journey.  We rotate the point cloud in multiple axes until the floor is as level as possible, or until columns are as plumb as can be.  It is usually rotated in at least 2 axes, and can be rotated and bumped 7 or 8 times to get it true. So I need all the transform info except scale and mirroring.  I have added the code I wrote earlier to save the trans to a 16 digit text file, and that gets pasted into an ACAD script that matches the point cloud location in ACAD, it works perfectly, it's the Revit rotation that's causing trouble (now that I need edewise data to match)

Comment: The rotation is centered about the source objects origin and not the target object,  how do I move the rotational axis from one origin to the other origin without reorienting it?

Comment: ARRRGGG!!!    Ok,  If I pick a CAD import(source) that has been rotated, and then pick either a point cloud(target) or a Revit Link(target) the targets rotate as expected.  however If I pick the point cloud(source) first and then the Revit Link(target) the link does not rotate.  Even stranger, If I pick the point cloud(source) first and the CAD import(target) second, then the import dissapears (found out it's scale is being set to nan) ????  This testing was done with the move portion of the code disabled.

Comment: Ok,  Found out revit links cannot be rotated in any axis other than z, even with API.  The scaling to nan issue resulted from the point cloud having a scale other than 1 to begin with,  so I just change its scale temporarily and back again. With Revit Links out of the question,  I will try all of this with assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That makes sense to me. In Revit, it always helps to fully develop and test all detailed steps of your workflow in the user interface first and ensure you are following best practices before starting to attack the task programmatically.

Comment: FYI.  I have this all working now.   You Can put Piping into an assembly and run code to transform it as a whole(move/rotate), then un-assemble it.

Comment: Congratulations on solving it!